# Is their any simplified Java to find palindome dates between year 0000 and 9999?

Tags: java, arrays, date, palindrome

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PalindromeDates {

    static final int STARTINGYEAR = 0000;
    static final int ENDINGYEAR = 9999;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int year, month, date;
        int dateArray[];
        boolean flag;

        System.out.println("    Date   -->       Array Format\n");

        for (year = STARTINGYEAR; year <= ENDINGYEAR; year++) {
            for (month = 01; month <= 12; month++) {
                for (date = 1; date <= 31; date++) {

                    if (checkValidDate(year, date, month)) {
                        dateArray = createDateArray(date, month, year);
                        flag = checkPalindrome(dateArray);
                        if (flag) {
                            System.out.print(year + "." + month + "." + date + "  -->  ");
                            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dateArray));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] createDateArray(int date, int month, int year) { //Inserting the whole date to an array

        int dateArray[] = new int[8];

        dateArray[0] = year / 1000;
        year = year % 1000;
        dateArray[1] = year / 100;
        year = year % 100;
        dateArray[2] = year / 10;
        dateArray[3] = year % 10;

        dateArray[4] = month / 10;
        dateArray[5] = month % 10;

        dateArray[6] = date / 10;
        dateArray[7] = date % 10;

        return dateArray;
    }

    public static boolean checkPalindrome(int dateArray[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (dateArray[i] == dateArray[7 - i]) {
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean checkValidDate(int year, int month, int date) {

        if (month == 2 && date == 30)
            return false;

        if ((month == 2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (date == 31)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ((month == 2) && (date == 29))
            return (checkLeapYear(year));

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean checkLeapYear(int year) {

        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if (year % 100 == 0) {
                if (year % 400 == 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            } else
                return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This program is written by me to find the palindrome dates since 0000 to 9999. Is their any simplifies program to do this?. What are the modifications for this code? And I want to know whether my leap year finding code is correct.

There is a method called `createDateArray()`. It is used to put the integer digits in year, month, date to an array. Is there any simple method to do that?

Comment: Why are you using `0000` instead of a single `0` ?

Comment: Also you should clarify what you mean by *simplified*? What is the specific problem you are seeking to solve?

Comment: *FYI:* The `checkLeapYear` code can be simplified by reversing the conditions, so you don't need `else` clauses: `if (year % 4 != 0) { return false; } if (year % 100 != 0) { return true; } if (year % 400 != 0) { return false; } return true;` --- Of course, it could also be just a return statement: `return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));`

Answer (score 3):

I am inferring from your code that a palindrome date is a date that formatted into yyyyMMdd format is a palindrome string. For example the day before yesterday, February 2, 2020, was a palindrome date because it’s formatted into 20200202, a palindrome.

> Is their any simplifies program to do this? …

Yes there is. See below.

> … And I want to know whether my leap year finding code is correct.

Yes, it is correct. I have tested its result against the result of `Year.of(y).isLeap()` for `y` ranging from 0 through 9999.

And the issue you didn’t ask about: as jrook hinted in a comment, beware of octal numbers.

```
    static final int STARTINGYEAR = 0000;
```

While this works in this case, it works for reasons that I am afraid that you don’t fully understand. You will get surprises if some day you try 0500 for year 500 and get 320, or you use 0008 for year 8 and get a compile time error. When a Java integer literal begins with 0 (and has more digits following it), it is an octal number, not a number in the decimal number system. So in your code you should use `0` for the year that you want printed as `0000`:

```
    static final int STARTINGYEAR = 0;
```

### java.time

On one side Andreas is correct in the other answer that this goes a lot more smoothly when using the date classes that are built into Java. On the other side the `Calendar` class used in that answer is poorly designed and long outdated. So I recommend we don’t use it and instead present a solution using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    List<LocalDate> palindromeDates = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
            .flatMap(m -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, m.length(true)).mapToObj(d -> MonthDay.of(m, d)))
            .map(md -> md.atYear(reverseStringToInt(md.format(monthDayFormatter))))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    palindromeDates.forEach(ld -> System.out.println(ld.format(dateFormatter)));
```

This code uses a few auxiliaries:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter monthDayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdd");
private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");

private static int reverseStringToInt(String s) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(s);
    buf.reverse();
    return Integer.parseInt(buf.toString());
}
```

Excerpt from the output:

> ```
> 01011010
> 01100110
> 01111110
> 01200210
> …
> 20111102
> 20200202
> 20211202
> …
> 92800829
> 92900929
> ```

The algorithm idea is stolen from Andreas’ answer since it is so well thought.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 2):

Since the year can be any 4-digit year, there is no constraint there, so just go through all 366<sup>1</sup> `MMdd` values of a year, reverse it and use as the year.

<sup>*1) Since the leap date of `0229` reversed is `9220`, it **is** a leap year, and hence a valid palindrome date.*</sup>

As code, using `Calendar`, in year order:

```
List<String> palimdromeDates = new ArrayList<>();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"/*No DST*/));
cal.clear();
cal.set(2000/*Leap Year*/, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
for (; cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 2000; cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)) {
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int year = 0; // Calculate: year = reverse(MMdd)
    for (int i = 0, n = month * 100 + day; i < 4; i++, n /= 10)
        year = year * 10 + n % 10;
    palimdromeDates.add(String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day));
}
Collections.sort(palimdromeDates); // Sort by year
for (String date : palimdromeDates)
    System.out.println(date);
```

Note that this code only loops 366 times, and does not create any unnecessary `String` objects or other type of objects, so it is very fast, and generates minimum garbage.

*Output*

```
0101-10-10
0110-01-10
0111-11-10
0120-02-10
0121-12-10
0130-03-10
0140-04-10
0150-05-10
0160-06-10
0170-07-10
0180-08-10
0190-09-10
0201-10-20
0210-01-20
0211-11-20
0220-02-20
0221-12-20
0230-03-20
0240-04-20
0250-05-20
0260-06-20
0270-07-20
0280-08-20
0290-09-20
0301-10-30
0310-01-30
0311-11-30
0321-12-30
0330-03-30
0340-04-30
0350-05-30
0360-06-30
0370-07-30
0380-08-30
0390-09-30
1001-10-01
1010-01-01
1011-11-01
1020-02-01
1021-12-01
1030-03-01
1040-04-01
1050-05-01
1060-06-01
1070-07-01
1080-08-01
1090-09-01
1101-10-11
1110-01-11
1111-11-11
1120-02-11
1121-12-11
1130-03-11
1140-04-11
1150-05-11
1160-06-11
1170-07-11
1180-08-11
1190-09-11
1201-10-21
1210-01-21
1211-11-21
1220-02-21
1221-12-21
1230-03-21
1240-04-21
1250-05-21
1260-06-21
1270-07-21
1280-08-21
1290-09-21
1301-10-31
1310-01-31
1321-12-31
1330-03-31
1350-05-31
1370-07-31
1380-08-31
2001-10-02
2010-01-02
2011-11-02
2020-02-02
2021-12-02
2030-03-02
2040-04-02
2050-05-02
2060-06-02
2070-07-02
2080-08-02
2090-09-02
2101-10-12
2110-01-12
2111-11-12
2120-02-12
2121-12-12
2130-03-12
2140-04-12
2150-05-12
2160-06-12
2170-07-12
2180-08-12
2190-09-12
2201-10-22
2210-01-22
2211-11-22
2220-02-22
2221-12-22
2230-03-22
2240-04-22
2250-05-22
2260-06-22
2270-07-22
2280-08-22
2290-09-22
3001-10-03
3010-01-03
3011-11-03
3020-02-03
3021-12-03
3030-03-03
3040-04-03
3050-05-03
3060-06-03
3070-07-03
3080-08-03
3090-09-03
3101-10-13
3110-01-13
3111-11-13
3120-02-13
3121-12-13
3130-03-13
3140-04-13
3150-05-13
3160-06-13
3170-07-13
3180-08-13
3190-09-13
3201-10-23
3210-01-23
3211-11-23
3220-02-23
3221-12-23
3230-03-23
3240-04-23
3250-05-23
3260-06-23
3270-07-23
3280-08-23
3290-09-23
4001-10-04
4010-01-04
4011-11-04
4020-02-04
4021-12-04
4030-03-04
4040-04-04
4050-05-04
4060-06-04
4070-07-04
4080-08-04
4090-09-04
4101-10-14
4110-01-14
4111-11-14
4120-02-14
4121-12-14
4130-03-14
4140-04-14
4150-05-14
4160-06-14
4170-07-14
4180-08-14
4190-09-14
4201-10-24
4210-01-24
4211-11-24
4220-02-24
4221-12-24
4230-03-24
4240-04-24
4250-05-24
4260-06-24
4270-07-24
4280-08-24
4290-09-24
5001-10-05
5010-01-05
5011-11-05
5020-02-05
5021-12-05
5030-03-05
5040-04-05
5050-05-05
5060-06-05
5070-07-05
5080-08-05
5090-09-05
5101-10-15
5110-01-15
5111-11-15
5120-02-15
5121-12-15
5130-03-15
5140-04-15
5150-05-15
5160-06-15
5170-07-15
5180-08-15
5190-09-15
5201-10-25
5210-01-25
5211-11-25
5220-02-25
5221-12-25
5230-03-25
5240-04-25
5250-05-25
5260-06-25
5270-07-25
5280-08-25
5290-09-25
6001-10-06
6010-01-06
6011-11-06
6020-02-06
6021-12-06
6030-03-06
6040-04-06
6050-05-06
6060-06-06
6070-07-06
6080-08-06
6090-09-06
6101-10-16
6110-01-16
6111-11-16
6120-02-16
6121-12-16
6130-03-16
6140-04-16
6150-05-16
6160-06-16
6170-07-16
6180-08-16
6190-09-16
6201-10-26
6210-01-26
6211-11-26
6220-02-26
6221-12-26
6230-03-26
6240-04-26
6250-05-26
6260-06-26
6270-07-26
6280-08-26
6290-09-26
7001-10-07
7010-01-07
7011-11-07
7020-02-07
7021-12-07
7030-03-07
7040-04-07
7050-05-07
7060-06-07
7070-07-07
7080-08-07
7090-09-07
7101-10-17
7110-01-17
7111-11-17
7120-02-17
7121-12-17
7130-03-17
7140-04-17
7150-05-17
7160-06-17
7170-07-17
7180-08-17
7190-09-17
7201-10-27
7210-01-27
7211-11-27
7220-02-27
7221-12-27
7230-03-27
7240-04-27
7250-05-27
7260-06-27
7270-07-27
7280-08-27
7290-09-27
8001-10-08
8010-01-08
8011-11-08
8020-02-08
8021-12-08
8030-03-08
8040-04-08
8050-05-08
8060-06-08
8070-07-08
8080-08-08
8090-09-08
8101-10-18
8110-01-18
8111-11-18
8120-02-18
8121-12-18
8130-03-18
8140-04-18
8150-05-18
8160-06-18
8170-07-18
8180-08-18
8190-09-18
8201-10-28
8210-01-28
8211-11-28
8220-02-28
8221-12-28
8230-03-28
8240-04-28
8250-05-28
8260-06-28
8270-07-28
8280-08-28
8290-09-28
9001-10-09
9010-01-09
9011-11-09
9020-02-09
9021-12-09
9030-03-09
9040-04-09
9050-05-09
9060-06-09
9070-07-09
9080-08-09
9090-09-09
9101-10-19
9110-01-19
9111-11-19
9120-02-19
9121-12-19
9130-03-19
9140-04-19
9150-05-19
9160-06-19
9170-07-19
9180-08-19
9190-09-19
9201-10-29
9210-01-29
9211-11-29
9220-02-29
9221-12-29
9230-03-29
9240-04-29
9250-05-29
9260-06-29
9270-07-29
9280-08-29
9290-09-29
```

Comment: Congrats on the 100 k, Andreas. Your wizard hat avatar very well suits the wizardry in code you’ve presented in SO answers for years now.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you. Yeah, it's quite a milestone. StackOverflow even sent me an email congratulating me. 

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");
for (LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1); d.isBefore(LocalDate.of(10000, 1, 1)); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
    String dateString = dateFormatter.format(d);
    if (dateString.equals(new StringBuilder(dateString).reverse().toString())) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: A simplified program was asked for. I must say that you are giving exactly that. Plus one. You may use `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` instead of rolling your own formatter.

Comment: Using `LocalDate.of(10000, 1, 1)` in the conditional part of the `for` loop could theoretically create 3652426 `LocalDate` instances, if JIT doesn't optimize that away. Also, this code creates 7304850 `String` objects and 3652425 `StringBuilder` objects, so it is not that great for performance. But it is simple concise code, so for that you get an up-vote from me.

Comment: Also a slightly simpler comparison: `dateString.contentEquals(new StringBuilder(dateString).reverse())`.